# How to get partial string query matches in Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I search for 'stone', I want my query to return

```
{ first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone', }
```

[However, the docs suggest I need to search for an exact match only.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)

```
usersRef.where("last", "==", "Flintstone")
```

And will not return a partial match of 'stone'.

Is there a way to get partial string search matches?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by firebase as the link you shared mentioned, probably you want to use some tool like algolia to achieve that use case, and keep it in sync with firestore using cloud functions.